# How do I get started in NLP using C#?

Tags: c#, nlp

I come from a linguistic background and I'm pretty new to the programming community (and feeling kind of lost actually).

I have been actively learning the basics of C# in the last weeks, which will be the language I'll be working with for a few NLP projects in my PhD program.

I don't know at all where and how to get started on this. I'd like to learn how to consume web services in C# for different sets of NLP tasks such as POS tagging or sentence tokenization. Everything I've looked for up to this moment feels like far away from my current understanding. So, if you happen to know anything about NLP in connection to C# that could guide me in the right direction, I would highly appreciate it.

Comment: Unfortunately, this type of question is off topic on SO. We don't give broad answers / suggest resources. I would link you to the help pages with better verbiage, but I'm on mobile.

Comment: I would rather suggest leaning towards tensorflow (Deep Learning Library TensorFlow
) that you can program with Python, C, Go, Java or Javascript.

Comment: Sadly, C# is not well supported with libraries for these types of tasks. You would have to do a lot of work yourself. Try looking into python, there are many libraries such as spacy, nltk, sklearn, keras, tensorflow and many more.